# Selenium docker dynamic grid set timezone to containers generated dynamically

Tags: docker, selenium, docker-compose, selenium-docker

I'm trying to run selenium hub with nodes generated dynamically with docker.
Here is my docker compose file.

```
  node-docker:
    image: selenium/node-docker:${SELENIUM_DOCKER_TAG}
    container_name: node-docker
    volumes:
      - ${SELENIUM_ASSETS}:/opt/selenium/assets
      - ./config.toml:/opt/bin/config.toml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_VNC_VIEW_ONLY=1
      - SE_VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1
      - TZ=${SELENIUM_TZ}
      - NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=${SELENIUM_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS}
      - NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=${SELENIUM_MAX_SESSIONS}
    restart: always

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:${SELENIUM_DOCKER_TAG}
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
    environment:
      - SE_OPTS=--allow-cors true
      - TZ=${SELENIUM_TZ}
    restart: always
```

And the config.toml file is as follow:

```
[docker]
# Configs have a mapping between the Docker image to use and the capabilities that need to be matched to
# start a container with the given image.
configs = [
    "selenium/standalone-firefox:4.4.0-20220812", "{\"browserName\": \"firefox\"}",
    "selenium/standalone-chrome:4.4.0-20220812", "{\"browserName\": \"chrome\"}",
    "selenium/standalone-edge:4.4.0-20220812", "{\"browserName\": \"MicrosoftEdge\"}"
    ]

# URL for connecting to the docker daemon
# Most simple approach, leave it as http://127.0.0.1:2375, and mount /var/run/docker.sock.
# 127.0.0.1 is used because interally the container uses socat when /var/run/docker.sock is mounted
# If var/run/docker.sock is not mounted:
# Windows: make sure Docker Desktop exposes the daemon via tcp, and use http://host.docker.internal:2375.
# macOS: install socat and run the following command, socat -4 TCP-LISTEN:2375,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock,
# then use http://host.docker.internal:2375.
# Linux: varies from machine to machine, please mount /var/run/docker.sock. If this does not work, please create an issue.
url = "http://127.0.0.1:2375"
# Docker image used for video recording
video-image = "selenium/video:ffmpeg-4.3.1-20220812"

# Uncomment the following section if you are running the node on a separate VM
# Fill out the placeholders with appropriate values
#[server]
#host = <ip-from-node-machine>
#port = <port-from-node-machine>
```

My problem is that the container generated dynamically has a UTC timezone instead of my timezone (America/Montreal) set in my environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

To set the timezone for dynamic container we need de set `"se:timeZone"` in browser option capabilities.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).